# export_fig TIFF with 500DPI

Tags: matlab

I try to save the handles.imgAxes to a tiff with 500DPI without sucess, any idea why?

```
export_fig(handles.imgAxes, Name,  '-tiff -r500');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export_fig(handles.imgAxes, Name, '-tiff', '-r500')`

Comment: thx for the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the format and the resolution should be two separate inputs

```
export_fig(handles.imgAxes, Name, '-tiff', '-r500')
```